# some letters are converted into a special characters during json.dump in python 3.6

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this following string,

'Your teams must understand their part in achieving business outcomes. Teams need to understand their roles in the success of other teams, the role of other teams in their success, and have shared goals. Understanding responsibility, ownership, how decisions are made, and who has authority to make decisions will help focus **eﬀorts** and maximize the **beneﬁts** from your teams.'

Where i see two words (benifits and efforts are not contains a proper letters) efforts (the ff are basically a special character and for benefits the fi is not a proper letter.

Is there a to form this string properly?

Python version is 3.6

Thanks in advannce,

Comment: Post your code, its output, and your desired output.

Comment: If you want the `ﬀ` and `ﬁ` to be `ff` and `fi` respectively, normalize the string: `unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "eﬀorts and maximize the beneﬁts")`

Comment: Wow. This actually solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, these are (one type of) ligatures, [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)#Stylistic_ligatures)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.